# Css Ellipsis creating issues

Tags: css

I'm trying to ellipsis the long text, but my issue is I have a `<div>` and `<span>` to be placed next to each other. If i set a certain width it pushes the `<span>` to the right as shown in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NawcT/430/

I dont want to show that white space when the text is not long enough as seen in ex:2 in the fiddle. It needs adjust the width depending on size of text. Is it possible?

html:

```
<div>
<div class="oneline">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789</div>
<span>Name</span>

<div class="oneline">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789g 456 </div>
<span>Name</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.oneline {
        text-overflow : ellipsis;
        white-space   : nowrap;
        width         : 50%;
        overflow      : hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-width:50%` That will allow the div to be upto 50% wide

```css
  .oneline {
        text-overflow : ellipsis;
        white-space   : nowrap;
        max-width         : 50%;
        overflow      : hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<div class="oneline">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789g 456 Testing 789</div>
<span>Name</span>
</div>

<div>
<div class="oneline">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789g 456 </div>
<span>Name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using max-width instead of width.

With width the width of the block is fixed whereas if you use a max-width that gives you the capability of a flexible width not exceeding the limit you provide here.